What is this anime serial where a teenager raises an alien child?
This serial is about a boy and girl who got an alien baby along with a talking cat-like pet... 
If I am remembering correctly the girl's name is Miu, not sure of that.
At first they hate each other and argue about household chores but as they grow up they fall in love and at the finale the baby comes as an toddler/teenager to find them living happily...

It must be UFO Baby. All the plot-points matches. Her name is Miyu. Its based on Manga. Here is a picture from it

I have watched it myself, so I can ensure it that it has the last episode where the UFO baby comes again to see that the girl and boy is now together and have their own child (with the same face).

That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks...I wish I can up-vote it..but, not have much reputation point.

@NehaSangore: The rest of us will have to upvote for you until you get your rep up then :)
